# How to get actual frame of subView of root view in ViewControtroller

Tags: ios, xib

I have a view and a subView which is of type `UIView` with constraints so that it's width is equal to its superview.(I use `auto Layout`)
However,when i try to get frame property of this subview in viewController in

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
 NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.subview.frame));//get subview's frame
}
```

method,I always get `{{0, 20}, {600, 320}}` which means its width is 600.

But the actual width is 320,did this mean that this subview hasn't been layouted when this method is called,and how could I get this actual width in this method?

Any help is appreciated,Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. `UIViewController` doesn't have a `subview` property, by default. Did you create this property? How are you adding the subView to the view?

Comment: @anthonyliao yes I have this outlet property which is subview of the view property

Comment: It will give you the correct results in viewDidAppear. viewDidLoad is too early to get the frames of subviews.

Answer (score 0):

subview's frame isn't valid in viewDidLoad -- it hasn't been laid out yet.  Move your code to viewDidLayoutSubviews.

If you find you have a dependency which requires you to look at the frame in viewDidLoad, you probably don't have your constraints designed correctly.  Look for areas where you can add more relationships between views. If that doesn't help, try modifying constraints programmatically -- when using autolayout, you almost never want to look at or explicitly change a view's frame.